# Java obtains (date and time) from Oracle, some of which are smaller than an hour, and some are normal

Tags: mybatis

Java obtains (date and time) from Oracle, some of which are smaller than an hour, and some are normal.

For example:

In the database: 1987-08-21 00:00:00

Back to the front end: 1987-08-20 23:00:00

For example, in the database, 1999-07-22 00:00:00, the foreground returns is 1999-07-22 00:00:00

**code:**

```
select dataOfBirth from pat_info where id=1;
database: id=1  dataOfBirth ：1987-08-21
```

Response Body：
"dataOfBirth":"1987-08-20 23:00:00"

jackson:
time-zone:GMT+8
data-format:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Thanks for your help

Comment: We would love to help, but what is your question? Your question should also contain some code.

Comment: Probably due to timezones.

Comment: @zoutq There is not enough information. Try creating a small project that replicate the issue. [Here](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues) are some templates and examples.